# Angular, mocking a promise with settimeout ($q)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am try ing to set up a test harness for a service, making it take about 1 second to play around with some stuff on the front end.

I am using a q so I can call a .then in the controller, so I figuired I could fake this for now by using set timeout, however I think my syntax is incorrect. Here is what I've tried:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        setTimeout(function() {

                        }, 1000).then(resolve);
                    });
```

I just want it to wait a second then resolve. New to this, would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed your syntax is incorrect. The [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function doesn't return a promise with a `.then()` method - instead, it takes a callback. You'd want to use

```
return $q(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
});
```

However, if you use Angular, you should just go for the [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which does return a promise right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
                    });
```

BTW: In angular you should use `$timeout` service instead of the javascript `setTimeout`

Aanyway, in the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) you find also an example with your use case.